# Extract id with matching pattern on several rows in dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, match

Here is an example of a dataframe I'm working on :

```
id  string
1    no
1    yes
1    yes
2    no
2    yes
3    yes
3    yes
3    no
```

I want to extract the `id` for which the **last two rows** contain the string `"yes"` for the column `string`.

So the results would be :

```
id   string
 1    yes
 1    yes
```

And I would have only one `id` which will be `1`.

I tried to do this with a for loop but since I have more than 200 000 lines, the loop is taking too much time : **more than 5 minutes**.

I tried this :

```
vec_id <- unique(df$id)

for(id in vec_id){
   if( tail(df[which(df$id == id),"string"])[1] & tail(df[which(df$id == id),"string"])[2] ){
      vec_id <- append(vec_id, id) 
     }
```

Are there any functions or ways to do this task more fastly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', `if` `all` the 'string' from the last two observations are 'yes' then get the last two 'string' (using `tail`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(all(tail(string,2)=="yes")) .(string = tail(string,2)) , id]
#  id string
#1:  1    yes
#2:  1    yes
```

NOTE: The data.table syntax is often `data.table[i, j, by]`.

Comment: It seems quite powerful but I have never seen a such syntax. Could you explain a bit this part : .(string = tail(string,2)) ? And also why they are two "," inside your "[]" ?

Comment: Ok I see but if I wanted to extract all the rows given by the condition `if(all(tail(string,2)=="yes"))` when it's `TRUE`, how would I do that ?

Comment: @MbrMbr  In that case, `.(string = string), id]` i.e. `setDT(df1)[, if(all(tail(string,2)=="yes")) .(string = string), id]`

Answer (score 2):

A base R alternative is to use `split` and `lapply` (with `unlist`) to construct a logical vector that can be used to perform the row subsetting:

```
dropper <- unlist(lapply(split(df$string, df$id),
                         FUN=function(i) c(rep(FALSE, length(i) - 2),
                                           rep(all(tail(i, 2) =="yes"), 2))),
                  use.names=FALSE)
dropper
FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Here, `split` splits the `df$string` into a list by `df$id` which is fed to an anonymous function by `lapply`. The function returns FALSE for the first n-2 elements and then either returns TRUE TRUE or FALSE FALSE for the final two elements depending on whether they are both "yes."

then use the vector to drop unwanted observations.

```
 df[dropper,]
  id string
2  1    yes
3  1    yes
```

Comment: Works great also.