# Find id with a minimal pattern on several rows with datatable R and check further

Tags: r, string, dataframe, data.table, match

An example of datatable I'm working on :

```
id     date     dayStop stop
1   2017/01/27     20    Y
1   2017/03/27      0    N
1   2017/04/27     10    Y
1   2017/05/27      0    N
1   2017/06/27      0    Y  
2   2017/01/27     20    Y
2   2017/03/27      0    N
2   2017/04/27     10    N
2   2017/05/27      0    N
2   2017/06/27      0    Y
2   2017/07/27      0    Y
3   2017/01/27     20    N
3   2017/03/27      0    Y
3   2017/04/27     10    Y
3   2017/05/27      0    Y
3   2017/06/27      0    Y
3   2017/06/28      0    Y
```

I want to extract the rows for each `ids` when the two last rows are `"Y"` `"Y"` :

```
library(data.table)
DT[, if(all(tail(stop,2)=="Y")) .(stop=stop) , id]
```

And I get :

```
id     date     dayStop stop
2   2017/01/27     20    Y
2   2017/03/27      0    N
2   2017/04/27     10    N
2   2017/05/27      0    N
2   2017/06/27      0    Y
2   2017/07/27      0    Y 
3   2017/01/27     20    N
3   2017/03/27      0    Y
3   2017/04/27     10    Y
3   2017/05/27      0    Y
3   2017/06/27      0    Y
3   2017/06/28      0    Y
```

In the end, I will get the `id` if `dayStop` > 20 or between two `"Y"` I have more than 20 days in difference (with the subtraction of the values of the colum `date` between two rows)

But if in the last two rows I have no value for `dayStop` nor enough days (<20), I need to check if the two `"Y"` are preceded by another `"Y"` and if it's the case, then I need to check if I have 20 days in difference between the new `"Y"` and the last `"Y"` and so on. (if it's `"N"`, the `id` will not be taken)

Example :

```
3   2017/06/27      0    Y
3   2017/06/28      0    Y
```

is not enough but :

```
3   2017/05/27      0    Y
3   2017/06/27      0    Y
3   2017/06/28      0    Y
```

is good because (2017/06/28) - (2017/05/27) > 20.

Is it possible to put a such condition in the j area of the datatable or a while loop will work efficiently ?

To copy paste the data.table :

```
id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
date <- as.Date(c("2017/01/27","2017/03/27","2017/04/27",
          "2017/05/27",
          "2017/06/27",
          "2017/01/27",
          "2017/03/27",
          "2017/04/27",
          "2017/05/27",
          "2017/06/27",
          "2017/07/27",
          "2017/01/27",
          "2017/03/27",
          "2017/04/27",
          "2017/05/27",
          "2017/06/27",
          "2017/06/28"))
dayStop <- c(20,0,10,0,0,20,0,10,0,0,0,20,0,10,0,0,0)
stop <- c("Y","N","Y","N","Y",
          "Y","N","N","N","Y","Y",
          "N","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y")
df <- data.frame(id, date, dayStop, stop)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
```

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860953/extract-id-with-matching-pattern-on-several-rows-in-dataframe/42861612#42861612) addresses your first question.

Comment: @lmo Indeed but what I have done is already further than the goal of the post you cited. I'm searching for other stuff.

Comment: @Omlere more people will probably have a crack at this if they can copy and paste your example data table into their R session. Hint: paste output of `dput(my.example.data.table)` or whatever you data table is called.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon You can easily read it using `fread` just as is.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I can't. Not without editing out the blank lines.

Comment: @Omlere Firs of all `DT[, if(all(tail(stop,2)=="Y")) .(stop=stop) , id]` doesn;t return what you are showing. You probably meant `DT[, if(all(tail(stop,2)=="Y")) .SD, by = id]`. Second of all, please show you full desired output (not just a partial group 2).

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon I have edited with the code if you want to check

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry I cc'd the wrong line of code, yours is better, yes. In the end of the algorithm, I just want the `id` that verify the conditions I have explained (maybe it's not clear). What I want to check if there no enough days between two `Y` is to check if there is third `Y` and check if between it and the last, the number of days are > 20 and so on. In this example, `id` `1`, `2` and `3` are correct.

Comment: @Omlere that's great. I was really just trying to ensure as many people as possible try to help. The way it is, it still implies effort on the part of the user (even if its minimal). It's soooooo much easier when you can copy/paste something directly into your R session with no effort, like `df <- structure(list(A = 1:3), .Names = "A", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")` which as an example is the output from `dput( data.frame( A = 1:3 ) )`. Anyway I see you added the code to do the copy paste which is great!